# Dominant morphism of Affine Scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose to have $\phi$ a ring morphsim from $A$ to $B$, let $X=SpecA$ , $Y=SpecB$ and $\psi$ the induced morphism of affine schemes. It's true that  if $\psi$ dominant than $\phi$ is injective?

Answer (score 0):

No, but yes for reduced rings. It may help to do exercise II.3.11 in Hartshorne.